# Why does my CheckedTextView icon jump around to different elements in my GridView?

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, checkedtextview

I have a `GridView` whose elements are based on a `FrameLayout` containing an `ImageView` and a `CheckedTextView`. The xml file for the FrameLayout is as follows:

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gridImage"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/image"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:adjustViewBounds="false">
</ImageView>
<CheckedTextView
android:id="@+id/imageTick"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
android:checkMark="@drawable/icon"
android:checked="false"
android:visibility="invisible"
>
</CheckedTextView>
</FrameLayout>
```

EDIT: This is the adapter's `getView()` method i use for each element:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.d("getView()", position+"");
        View v;
        ImageView imageView;
        if(convertView == null) {

            v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.photo_text_view, null);
            v.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100,100));
        }
        else
        {
            v = convertView;

        }
        imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(mThumbsIds.get().get(position));

        v.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        return v;
    }
```

In my activity class, I load a context menu and once i select an option i make the `CheckedTextView` visible for that `GridView` element like so :

```
GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    View selected =gridView.getChildAt(position);
    CheckedTextView selectedCheck = (CheckedTextView)selected.findViewById(R.id.imageTick);
    selectedCheck.setChecked(true);
    selectedCheck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

So two things can potentially happen from this point:

1) Lets say I picked the element at position 0, the CheckedTextView becomes visible, but when i scroll down my GridView, another element (e.g. position 17) has its CheckedTextView visible aswell. This continues on random elements as i scroll down towards the bottom.

2) If i pick an element towards the bottom, scroll back up to the top, and run one of methods to make all CheckedTextView's invisible, a `NullPointerException` is thrown for the element at the bottom. This happens at this point: `View selected =gridView.getChildAt(position);` where selected becomes null.

Whats going on here? Why do these random CheckedTextView's become visible and why do i get exceptions?

Comment: Most probably the problem lies in your Adapter code, you should post it.

Comment: I've added my adapter's getView() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems lie in the way you track checked items:

```
GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
View selected =gridView.getChildAt(position);
CheckedTextView selectedCheck = (CheckedTextView)selected.findViewById(R.id.imageTick);
selectedCheck.setChecked(true);
selectedCheck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

1) `getChildAt` will not give you the correct view if you've scrolled into content and you're indexing by adapter position. When referencing an active view in a `GridView` or `ListView` you want to do something like this:

```
final int index = position - gridView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
View selected = gridView.getChildAt(index);
```

The reason is that your `GridView` only keeps child views for adapter items that it is currently displaying. It may only have child views for elements 4 to 23 if elements 0 to 3 were scrolled off of the top earlier.

This is why you're getting exceptions when you do `View selected =gridView.getChildAt(position);` a view for that position does not actually exist when it's off-screen, so `getChildAt` returns `null`.

2) When a `ListView` or `GridView` has its content change or it otherwise needs to re-layout its child views, it does so by re-binding existing views using the `convertView` parameter to your adapter. Your adapter never adjusts the checked state of your item views, so a checked view can be reused for an item that *should* be unchecked later.

To solve this you should have your data model that your adapter presents track the checked state of your items rather than relying on the item views to do it. This means that your adapter should always verify/set the checked state of the item in `getView`. It may look something like this:

```
imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
imageView.setImageBitmap(mThumbsIds.get().get(position));

CheckedTextView checkView = (CheckedTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageTick);

if (mData.isItemChecked(position)) {
    checkView.setChecked(true);
    checkView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    checkView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Then when your option is selected that should change the checked state of an item, instead of the code snippet above do something like:

```
data.setItemChecked(position, true);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

`notifyDataSetChanged()` will tell the `GridView` that it should re-bind the item views, which will have your `getView` method fix up the checked states properly.

Comment: @adamp I will try your approach soon, thank you for your explanation. I have 1 quick question though, what is mData in your snippet?

Comment: It's just some theoretical way of tracking whether or not the item at each position within the adapter is checked. Adjust as necessary for your needs. :)

Comment: @adamp Thank you very much for your approach, it worked pretty well :) +1 for the explanation

Comment: Glad it worked out. :) While you're working with this code, you might take a look at some more info about ListView and GridView here: http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html - you can cache the results of the `findViewById` calls in your `getView` method for later using the ViewHolder pattern for added performance on older/slower handsets.

Comment: Great video, wasn't expecting to see you in the video! :P

Comment: That's just a bonus. ;) Great to hear that you enjoyed it.